# Flexslider 2 with vimeo not loading correctly chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have a page on a website which has a flexslider with 5 image slides and 5 video slides. The slider loads perfectly in IE and Firefox but in Chrome the slider can take up to about a minute to appear and often doesnt load until you resize the browser window or click on the page.

Here is a link to the website: http://10.scopus.com/people.php

EDIT:

Another point I have just noticed, if you resize the browser window it seems to instantly load in

EDIT:

Here is my code for the page

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Scopus 10</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/icon"
      href="http://live.scopus10.mkt/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flexslider.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/master.css" media="all">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/s.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.fitvid.js"></script>
<script src="http://f.vimeocdn.com/js_opt/froogaloop2.min.js?bfeb60ee"></script>
<!--[if IE]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="peoplevid loading">
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
<div class="first row">
  <div class="six columns"> <a href="#" class="active oliver">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="wrap"><img src="assets/images/people/oliver-dumon.jpg" alt="Oliver Dumon" /></div><div class="box"><span class="number">01</span><span class="dots">&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;</span><span class="name">Olivier<br />Dumon</span></div><div class="arrow"></div></a></div>
  <div class="six columns"> <a href="#" class="nick">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="wrap"><img src="assets/images/people/nick-fowler.jpg" alt="Nick Fowler" /></div><div class="box"><span class="number">02</span><span class="dots">&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;</span><span class="name">Nick<br />Fowler</span></div><div class="arrow"></div></a> </div>
  <div class="six columns"> <a href="#" class="mhamed">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="wrap"><img src="assets/images/people/mhamed-el-aisati.jpg" alt="M'hamed El Aisati" /></div><div class="box"><span class="number">03</span><span class="dots">&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;</span><span class="name">M'hamed<br />El Aisati</span></div><div class="arrow"></div></a> </div>
  <div class="six columns"> <a href="#" class="lisa">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="wrap"><img src="assets/images/people/lisa-colledge.jpg" alt="Lisa Colledge" /></div><div class="box"><span class="number">04</span><span class="dots">&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;</span><span class="name">Lisa<br />Colledge</span></div><div class="arrow"></div></a> </div>
  <div class="six columns"> <a href="#" class="eric">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="wrap"><img src="assets/images/people/eric-swenson.jpg" alt="Eric Swenson" /></div><div class="box"><span class="number">05</span><span class="dots">&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;</span><span class="name">Eric<br />Swenson</span></div><div class="arrow"></div></a> </div>
  <div class="six columns"> <a href="#" class="robbertjan">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="wrap"><img src="assets/images/people/robbertjan-kalff.jpg" alt="Robbertjan Klaff" /></div><div class="box"><span class="number">06</span><span class="dots">&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;&#8226;</span><span class="name">Robbertjan<br />Kalff</span></div><div class="arrow"></div></a> </div>
</div>
<div class="people">
  <ul class="slides">

    <li class="oliver">
      <div class="person">
      <div class="loadingslide"><h1>Loading..</h1></div>
        <ul>
          <li><img src="assets/images/people/large/oliver-dumon.jpg" alt="Oliver Dumon"/><span class="firstname">Olivier</span><span class="lastname">Dumon</span>
            <div class="greybar">
              <p>Managing Director, Academic & Government Research Markets</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <iframe class="quick-video" id="player_96519139" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/96519139?api=1&amp;player_id=player_96519139" width="100%" height="583px" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nick">
      <div class="person">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="assets/images/people/large/nick-fowler.jpg" alt="Nick Fowler"/><span class="firstname">Nick</span><span class="lastname">Fowler</span>
            <div class="greybar">
              <p>Managing Director, Academic & Government Institutional Markets</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <iframe class="quick-video" id="player_96518302" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/96518302?api=1&amp;player_id=player_96518302" width="100%" height="557px" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="mhamed">
      <div class="person">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="assets/images/people/large/mhamed-el-aisati.jpg" alt="M'hamed El Aisati"/><span class="firstname">M'hamed</span><span class="lastname">El Aisati</span>
            <div class="greybar">
              <p>Director Content & Analytics</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <iframe class="quick-video" id="player_96518301" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/96518301?api=1&amp;player_id=player_96518301" width="100%" height="557px" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="lisa">
      <div class="person">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="assets/images/people/large/lisa-colledge.jpg" alt="M'hamed El Aisati"/><span class="firstname">Lisa</span><span class="lastname">Colledge</span>
            <div class="greybar">
              <p>Senior Manager Strategic Alliances</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <iframe class="quick-video" id="player_96518300" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/96518300?api=1&amp;player_id=player_96518300" width="100%" height="557px" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="eric">
      <div class="person">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="assets/images/people/large/eric-swenson.jpg" alt="Eric Swenson"/><span class="firstname">Eric</span><span class="lastname">Swenson</span>
            <div class="greybar">
              <p>Director of Product Management, Scopus</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <iframe class="quick-video" id="player_96518298" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/96518298?api=1&amp;player_id=player_96518298" width="100%" height="557px" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="robbertjan">
      <div class="person">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="assets/images/people/large/robbertjan-kalff.jpg" alt="Robbertjan Kalff"/><span class="firstname">Robbertjan</span><span class="lastname">Kalff</span>
            <div class="greybar">
              <p>Vice President of Product Strategy</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <iframe class="quick-video" id="player_96521077" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/96521077?api=1&amp;player_id=player_96521077" width="100%" height="557px" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="prev">Back</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="next">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript to run the sliders

```
$('.people').flexslider({
        selector: "ul.slides > li",
        animation: 'slide',
        slideshow: false,
        start: function (slider) {
            current_slide = slider.currentSlide + 1;
            total_slides = slider.count;


        },
        after: function (slider) {
            current_slide = slider.currentSlide + 1;
            total_slides = slider.count;

        }

    });



    $('.person').flexslider({
        animation: 'slide',
        selector: "ul > li",
        slideshow: false,
        start: function (slider) {
        $('.person').flexslider(0)

        }


    });
```

Comment: Can you please add some code and not just your site - I would use your browser console and see what issues you can solve....from the looks of it, you are getting errors: http://livepassdl.conviva.com/lpconfig/cfg/c3.customerName=c3.Vimeo&c3.platform=JS&c3.sver=2.82.0.19066?random=2393426989&uuid=1615390388.1996973301.3909775304.2153145567.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding these 4 lines of code:

```
 var slider1 = $('.people').data('flexslider');
slider1.resize();
var slider2 = $('.person').data('flexslider');
slider2.resize();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very inline! Do it the API way:

```
  var player = document.getElementById('player_1');
  $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);

  function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
      element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false)
    } else {
      element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
    }
  }
```

You can grab this from their site:
[**FLEXSLIDER w API Video (VIMEO)**](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/video.html)

I can only think that the only reason you are not using it this base is that you are using some CMS tool, but if not this is the way to go.

Comment: This is probably a better way to do it, but the deadline was tight and didnt have time to go back and change!